# Pip Error python

Tags: python, pip

I've got an error when I would like to get pip upgrade or to install a package. I know that my answer could be in this forum, but I don't find it.

So my error is  :

> Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in
>   main
>       status = self.run(options, args)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 290,
>   in run
>       requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)   File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1178, in
>   prepare_files
>       url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)   File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 292, in
>   find_requirement
>       elif is_prerelease(version) and not (self.allow_all_prereleases or req.prereleases):   File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/util.py", line 739, in
>   is_prerelease
>       return any([any([y in set(["a", "b", "c", "rc", "dev"]) for y in x]) for x in parsed]) TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Storing debug log for failure in /home/user/.pip/pip.log

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: you could try the command again and replace `pip` by `pip2` or `pip3`, that sometimes fixes those errors

Comment: Thanks it works with pip2 ;)

Comment: If you're using Debian or something Debian-like, see this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206136/91177